# LuaTeX - printing string literal producing strange dots

Tags: luatex, strings, lua

When I try to print a literal string with LuaTeX, these strange dots appear. Does anyone know why? Any suggestions to work around this?

I was thinking of parsing the literal string line by line and printing, something like below, but I'm curious as to why the dots are appearing.

```
function printLines(str)
    for line in str:gmatch"[^\n]*" do
        tex.sprint(line)
    end
end
```

[image]

main.tex:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{luacode}

\directlua{dofile("code.lua")} 

\begin{document}
\luaexec{
tex.sprint(tab)
}

\luaexec{
tex.sprint(tabBeg)
tex.sprint(tabMid)
tex.sprint(tabEnd)
}

\end{document}
```

code.lua:

```lua
tab = [[
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                test & table \\
                \end{tabular}
                
]]

tabBeg = [[\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}]]
tabMid = [[test & table \\]]
tabEnd = [[\end{tabular}]]
```

Comment: These dots are actually line break characters (e.g. `\n`). You can eliminate them by simply removing all `\n` in your string.

Comment: I'd rather not modify the content of `tab`, perhaps replacing them with \newline ought to do the trick.

Comment: Why are you using luainputenc and t1enc?

Comment: @likethevegetable It's not about the new line command that you entered (`\\ `), it is the line break characters (`\n`) you entered when you are defining `tab` as a **raw string**. When LaTeX's pre-processor reads input, it eliminates all line break characters, which means LaTeX does not understand what `\n` means. It is therefore represented by dots. You can try `local newtab = string.gsub(tab, "\n", "")` and print `newtab` to LaTeX. Now the dots will go away.